How to toggleclass for each label checkboxes in jquery?
I want to toggle class for the below code but not working. I want to add the class "checkbox-active" to each label when clicked and remove that class if clicked again.
<div class="sc-97ae821b-0 kgLRyG">
    <label id="selector-wrapper" class="sc-dc4336f8-0 jEDHBt sc-b5b652d3-0 eRKHhZ sc-97ae821b-1 jqCZMD problem-label" tabindex="0">
    <input name="problemAreas" type="checkbox" class="sc-dc4336f8-1 hvrnmr" value="CHEST">

    <label id="selector-wrapper" class="sc-dc4336f8-0 jEDHBt sc-b5b652d3-0 eRKHhZ sc-97ae821b-1 jqCZMD problem-label" tabindex="0">
    <input name="problemAreas" type="checkbox" class="sc-dc4336f8-1 hvrnmr" value="HAND">
</div>

What I have tried:
$(function() {
   $('.sc-dc4336f8-0').click(function() { // when a .myDiv is clicked
     
     $(this).addClass('checkbox-active');

     if($(this).hasClass('checkbox-active')){
           $(this).removeClass('checkbox-active').addClass('checkbox-active');
           
       }
   })
 })

The above code is working but what I want is that I want to remove the class "checkbox-active" also onclick if that label already has the class "checkbox-active"

Your code isn't looking for elements with class myDiv like suggested, not trying to manipulate the class of label elements or applying a class named ad-active. Please correct either your code snippet or the question to make them make sense together.

I have edited. Can you please check

Your question, given your code snippet, still doesn't make much sense I'm afraid. You could start by giving your elements unique IDs (ie: you have two labels sharing the same ID).

I took I guess on what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/o0rvabxn/

You can try below script. I have added "on()" function on input class.
$('.sc-dc4336f8-1').on('change', function() {
                        $(this).toggleClass('checkbox-active')});
})


Man, you saved my life. Thanks. But why "on click" is not working, can you please tell me?
